# Configurable products in shopping cart price rules in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have set up some cart price rules that provide a bulk discount for products in a certain category. It works fine for simple products but unfortunately it seems to ignore configurable products. My rules are:

[image: Shopping Cart Rules]

Is there a setting I need to change to include configurable products?

Comment: The price of the configurable product is made up from the prices of the simple products so I think it should work. Can you give more information about what isn't working for 'configurable' products?

Comment: Simply that when you add a configurable product to the cart, and select the option (ie the simple), the cart rule isn't being implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments I think we both agree this is irregular. Double check that the configurable and the simple products are in the same category, and then (you are probably doing this already) add a simple product to the cart and add the same simple product via a configured product and take a look at the results.

But before you do that, follow carefully my (paranoid) process for applying sale rules (this is what I do for Catalog Price Rules and shouldn't really be necessary for shopping cart rules but when Magento-based paranoia creeps in I turn to my obsessive-compulsive behaviour):

1. Re-index everything
2. Refresh the caches
3. 'Save and apply' the rule to apply it to the fresh indexes
4. Re-index again
5. Refresh the caches again

Now test the sales rules. The process is paranoid because for sure not everything needs re-indexed nor cache-refreshed and I haven't read all the code to understand from which tables or caches Magento build's its sale rule information from, but from real-life practice I know it can be difficult to get Magento to apply the rules.

I am not aware of a setting to explicitly include configurable products.

Check that there are not other rules with logic that excludes the configurable product.

If it remains a mystery, maybe creating a new configurable with only one simple item would help flush out the setting or glitch that is causing this behaviour - I think that would be a good point to start debugging if you need to roll up your sleeves and get into the code.

Comment: I spoke too soon. I have some configurable products that are configurable on an attribute called pack_size (ie one item with a pack size of 10 is actually treated as 10 items in the rule). These products work, as do simples, but configurable products with any other configurable attribute do not get the discount. Weird.